# `newStdGen` breaks referential transparency of `getStdGen`?

Tags: haskell

I'm reading some [samples about randomness in "Learn You a Haskell"](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output#randomness) and I got slightly confused about `newStdGen`. According to the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html), it updates internal variables so that `getStdGen` will produce something different next time it's called. That doesn't sound like referential transparency. Indeed, the following program shows that further calls to `getStdGen` produce different results, at least when monadically bound to variables:

```
import System.Random
main = do
  gen <- getStdGen
  putStrLn $ take 20 ( randomRs ('a','z') gen)
  newStdGen
  gen <- getStdGen
  putStrLn $ take 20 ( randomRs ('a','z') gen)
```

> ```
> λ> main
> dgnatnxgvammlgxgeumk
> rrxxnwupmbnxpxrkofjw
> ```

I appreciate that the type of `getStdGen` is `IO StdGen`, which is "an IO action that, when performed, will produce a `StdGen`," and that the bind operation

```
gen <- getStdGen
```

binds each `StdGen` to a (sequentially local) variable `gen`. Perhaps the solution is simply that the sequence of monadic `bind` operations implicit in the `do` syntax ensures that the two `gen` variables are different.

I'd be grateful for a confirmation or refutation of my reasoning and for any further clarification that would make this seem less spooky.

**EDIT**:

Comments helped me realize that my deeper confusion concerns the *appearance* of calling `getStdGen` twice with the same arguments (namely none) and getting different results. The property of getting the same results for the same arguments is not called *referential transparency*, so my question was misleading. What’s going on behind the scenes is similar to what’s going on in `State`, as pointed out by user2407038: the results are functions of hidden states, which are threaded together inside the bind operations.

Comment: Referential transparency does not apply to the results of IO actions. Otherwise, how would you be able to get more than one line of input with `getLine`?

Comment: There is no breaking of referential transparency since this program is in `IO` (particularly, there's no way to rewrite it to not use `IO`). This is no different than having a `State StdGen ()` and writing `do { x <- get; modify changeTheStateSomehow; y <- get; return (x,y) }`. I hope you agree this program should produce a tuple of two different values (unless `changeTheStateSomehow` happens to be the identity). Also note: your program has two different `gen` variables - they just happen to both be named `gen`. In the scope of the 2nd one, the 1st one is no longer accessible.

Comment: If you enable `-Wall` you will get a warning about `gen` being shadowed. Thus I would say those two variables are different. Also I think it is hard to talk about referential transparency inside an `IO`-block, but only outside of it. But I am not really firm in the theoretical foundations of the `IO`-monad.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe AFAIK, the only semantics of `IO` is "These actions will be performed in the order that they are composed.". Even that is questionable due to the existence of `unsafeInterleaveIO`, but it has `unsafe` in its name, so maybe it doesn't count.

Comment: "Perhaps the solution is simply that the sequence of monadic bind operations implicit in the do syntax ensures that the two gen variables are different." Yes. If you translate out of `do` syntactic sugar, you'll see they are arguments of two different lambdas: `get >>= (gen -> ... get >>= gen -> ...)`.

Comment: @user2407038 Later chapters of LYAH explain `State` http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#state, which further clarifies that we can have code that looks like it’s calling the same function with the same arguments but getting different results.

Answer (score 5):

Referential transparency says that you can replace a variable with its definition (or vice versa) without changing the meaning of the program. (The "reference" -- variable name -- is "transparent" -- you can't tell whether you're looking at the reference or the thing behind it.)

In this case, Haskell's module system is hiding pieces of the implementation, notably, `theStdGen :: IORef StdGen`, so we can't *technically* replace `newStdGen` with its implementation. But this is not a "deep" violation of referential transparency; if this part of the module were exposed, we could indeed replace `newStdGen` with its implementation, namely,

```
atomicModifyIORef' theStdGen split
```

and the meaning of the program would change not one whit. So there is no problem with referential transparency here.

Compare, e.g., this C snippet:

```
int referent[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
int *x = referent, *y = x;
x++;
printf("%d\n", *y);
```

Here if we replace `y` with its definition, `x`, we will get a program with a different meaning!

Compare also this Haskell snippet:

```
theStdGen :: IORef StdGen
theStdGen  = unsafePerformIO $ do
   rng <- mkStdRNG 0
   newIORef rng
```

If we were to replace `theStdGen` by its definition, that *would* change the meaning of the program -- instead of reusing the existing `IORef`, that would cause a fresh `IORef` to be created, and sharing would be lost. That is (part of) the meaning of the `unsafe` in `unsafePerformIO`: things that use `unsafePerformIO` may not be referentially transparent!